# Holomorphic function $f$ satisfying $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{|z|}$ on deleted neighborhoods of origin cannot have a double pole at origin?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let f be holomorphic on $D^*=\{z\in \mathbb C~:~0<|z|<1\}$ satisfying $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{|z|}$ for all $z \in D^*$, then prove or disprove that $f$ cannot have double pole at $z=0$.

Anything can be concluded from $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0}z^2f(z)=0$?

Comment: You are on the right track. What do you think the answer is? What is $\lim_{z \to 0 }z^2f(z)$ at a double pole?

Comment: Adding to what @MartinR said, you can consider using Riemann theorem on removable singularities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $g(z)=zf(z)$ is limited in a deleted neighborhood of $0$. Therefore, by Riemann's Extension Theorem, $g(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$. Can you conclude from here?